# I want to do something when user segues back in a navigation controller(iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a table view here and want to update the UI when user hit the 'back' button in a navigation controller. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are lots of avenues to accomplish something like this.

- Implement viewWillDisappear
- Implement viewWillAppear
- Set up a delegate for your navigation and respond to changes
- Make your own back button that links to your own function
- Use an NSNotification when moving back

Anyone of the above is a good starting place.

Comment: Thanks! I've been writing all these in ViewDidLoad. ViewWillAppear is the right place!

Answer (score 3):

Providing a code with your question would help us to help you !

Have you tried something like this ?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ? reload ? refresh? update with new data ?